# Segger RTT control block is not identified by RTT viewer

Tags: arm, cortex-m, jtag, segger-jlink

I'm trying to use Segger's RTT
([Real Time Transfer](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/technology/about-real-time-transfer/)),
but I'm not able to see any output on the RTT viewer.
I'm doubting that the root cause is an RTT control block not being identified by RTT viewer.

### Setup

The host PC is connected using Seggers's
[J-Link](https://www.segger.com/products/debug-probes/j-link/)
debugger (JTAG interface) to an ARM-CORTEX-M4 based board, like this:

```
[PC] <---- J-Link -----> [ generic CORTEX-M4 board]
```

### What I'm trying to achieve

I'm trying to integrate the RTT feature, which is specific to Segger, and I'm not able to see prints from RTT in the RTT viewer software on the host PC, by doing

1. Integrated code provided by segger

   ```
   SEGGER_RTT_Conf.h
   SEGGER_RTT_printf.c
   SEGGER-RTT.c
   SEGGER_RTT.h
   ```
2. Included `SEGGER_RTT.h` in my main file and added a call

   ```
   SEGGER_RTT_WriteString(0, "Hello World from SEGGER RTT!\r\n");
   ```

   within `main()`.
3. Using Eclipse and `arm-none-eabi-` toolchain to compile the application, as well as

   - `JLINK_GDBserverCL.exe` -- debug server
   - `arm-none-eabi-gdb`     -- debug client
   - Segger J-Link -- hardware debugger (connecting its JTAG interface)

   on host PC using RTT viewer software to receive prints in step #2.

I'm expecting to see a print in step #3, please help me to proceed.

Comment: Did you set the search range? SetRTTSearchRanges

Comment: I've found that using RTT (via Segger SysView) while JLinkGdbServer is running works very intermittently (<10%) - but if I quit GdbServer (leaving the target running) then SysView works perfectly.  (Windows 10 VSCode cortex-debug with an RP2040 target.)  I'm still investigating.

Answer (score 1):

Either you need to specify what specific device you're connecting when you call JLinkRTTViewer / JLinkRTTClient, or you need to find the memory address of "_SEGGER_RTT" in you .map file and pass that to the tools.